# Detached entity passed to persist with primary key that is also foreign key

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following tables in postgres:

```
create table USER(
    USER_ID SERIAL primary key,
    USER_NAME varchar(50) not null,
    PASSWORD varchar(120) not null,
)
```

And

```
create table ACCESS_TOKEN(
    USER_CODE INTEGER,
    TOKEN_CREATED DATE,
    TOKEN_VALUE VARCHAR(100),

    primary key (USER_CODE, TOKEN_CREATED),
    foreign key (USER_CODE) references USER(USER_ID),
)
```

and I have created the following entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_USER_ID_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "USER_USER_ID_SEQ", initialValue=1, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_USER_ID_SEQ_GEN")
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="USER_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String password;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCESS_TOKEN")
@IdClass(AccessToken.AccessTokenPK.class)
public class AccessToken implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_CODE", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @Id
    @Column(name="TOKEN_CREATED")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;


    @Column(name = "TOKEN_VALUE")
    private String token;


    public static class AccessTokenPK implements Serializable{
        protected int user;
        protected Date created;

        //constructor, hashbode, and equals
    }

}
```

However when I'm trying to persist the access token as following:

```
AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken();
accessToken.setUser(userEntity);
accessToken.setCreated(new Date());
accessToken.setToken("some string");
// persist token
dao.persist(accessToken);
```

I'm getting the following error

```
detached entity passed to persist: User
```

Comment: Is `User` a new entity? If so, have you tried the suggestions from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592247/in-jpa-having-a-many-to-one-as-primary-key-throws-referential-integrity-constra? Basically, the simplest solution seems to be to persist the `User` first, then the `AccessToken`. If not, please post the code you use to fetch the `User` entity from the persistent store.

Comment: User is an existing entity, I can solve this problem by passing a native insert query, but through JPA, it gives me this error

Comment: You need to make sure that when you call `dao.persist(accessToken)`, the `accessToken.user` field represents a managed entity. The easiest way to achieve that would be to call `accessToken.setUser(entityManager.getReference(User.class, userEntity.getId()))` before the call to `dao.persist`. You absolutely need to make all those calls within the scope of a transaction, though.

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate recognizes entities by its primary key.
try setting GenerationType.AUTO to Primary key of the User,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_USER_ID_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "USER_USER_ID_SEQ", initialValue=1, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "USER_USER_ID_SEQ_GEN")
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="USER_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String password;
}




@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCESS_TOKEN")
@IdClass(AccessToken.AccessTokenPK.class)
public class AccessToken implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_CODE", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @Id
    @Column(name="TOKEN_CREATED")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;


    @Column(name = "TOKEN_VALUE")
    private String token;


    public static class AccessTokenPK implements Serializable{
        protected int user;
        protected Date created;

        //constructor, hashbode, and equals
    }

}
```

Comment: how are you creating userEntity? here, accessToken.setUser(userEntity); try to hard code the primary key and pass it, if it works then that is the issue.

Comment: like this, UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
userEntity.setId(1234);